# Optimal join for joining facts with scd-type-2 dimension for aggregation/reporting

Tags: query-performance, join, data-warehouse, slowly-changing-dimension, apache-spark

I have a fact table and an scd-type-2 dimension table. I want to produce sales report by region and year.

I have working solution with a query that joins them for reporting purposes. When I run the query in spark/databricks, it gives me a little warning at the bottom: `Use range join optimization: This query has a join condition that can benefit from range join optimization. To improve performance, consider adding a range join hint.` and points to [this link](https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/range-join.html).

**Question:** Is there a more optimal way to query when I'm joining using a `between` condition (instead of `=` condition)?

`fact table:`

```sql
create table sales
(name             string
,sale_date        date
,sold_amt         long);

insert into sales values
('John','2022-02-02',100),
('John','2022-03-03',100),
('John','2023-02-02',200),
('John','2023-03-03',200),
('Rick','2022-02-02',300),
('Rick','2023-02-02',400);
```

`dimension table (scd-type-2)`

```sql
create table employee_scd2
(name        string
,region      string
,start_date  date,
,end_date    date,
,is_current  boolean); -- unused, kept for completeness

insert into employee_scd2 values
('John','NAM',  '2010-01-01', '2022-12-31', false),
-- John transferred from NAM to APAC starting 2023
('John','APAC', '2023-01-01', '9999-01-01', true),
('Rick','NAM',  '2020-01-01', '9999-12-31', true);
```

`sales report by region and year`

```sql
select e.region,
       year(s.sale_date) as sale_year,
       SUM(s.sold_amt)   as sale_amt
from       sales s
left join  employee_scd2 e
  on     e.name       = s.name
  and    s.sale_date between e.start_date and e.end_date
group by e.region, year(s.sale_date);
```

---

I've read following and some more:

- [Join Fact table to SCD Type 2 ... how to write query? (SQL Server)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184639/join-fact-table-to-scd-type-2-how-to-write-query-sql-server)
- https://www.startdataengineering.com/post/how-to-join-fact-scd2-tables/
- [How to implement Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD2) Type 2 in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

use range join optimization - it's intended to support this exact scenario.  You an also do a bit of z-ordering or bucketing of your data to help manage shuffling and data exchanging https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/range-join.html